# How to obtain href anchor texts ​from a div class using XPath

Tags: xpath

With XPath I want to filter out all anchor texts (a href) "click here", which are in a special div class "main-content" included. I am not a developer and hope for support, thank you.

Comment: Add the example html and expected result

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the a single div with the link. Here is [how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your query correctly you want to get all 'click here' links present in div with `main-content` class.

**Based on Link Text**

```
//div[contains(@class,'main-content')]//a[.='click here']
```

**Based on attribute:**

```
//div[contains(@class,'main-content')]//a[@href='url goes here']
```

Comment: This is the solution, thank you.

How should I change the XPath code, if I want to filter a special destination url (href="") instead of the link text?

Comment: Updated the answer with selection based on href attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It works fine.